# Checkbox checked property is undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I am adding rows and cols to html table programatically using Javascript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    table = document.getElementById("EntityRecords");
                    rowCount = table.rows.length;
                    row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
                    row.id = results[i].LeadId;
                    row.className = "EntityRecordsRow";

                    cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                    element = document.createElement("input");
                    element.type = "checkbox";
                    element.name = "chkbox[]";
                    cell1.appendChild(element);
                    cell1.className = "EntityRecordsCol";

                    cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                    cell2.innerHTML = results[i].FirstName + " " + results[i].LastName;
                }
```

On button click event, I need to find selected checkbox. I am reading the table cells using below code but checkbox cell `checked` property is undefined:

```
function OnRecordSelectionBtnClick() {
var table = document.getElementById("EntityRecords");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    var col = row.cells[0];
    if (col.checked) {
        var selectedText = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
        alert(selectedText);
    }
}
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you not checking the cell in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if ( col.firstElementChild.checked )`, not `if ( col.checked )`. `col` is td element and its first child is input that has `checked` property.